# Manwha about a female knight and princess regressing

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

i can't remember the name of this manwha where a female knight regressed back and then also find outs the princess regressed aswell in the first couple chapters. i think there was a plot to do with the collapse of the royal family and the princess being the only suriving member. there was also a bit where the female knight created a team of other skilled female knights.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the main characters' appearance or other significant characters or places?

Comment: When you say that they "regressed", do you mean that they woke up as their younger selves? Also, who is the main character: the knight or the princess?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Straight to the Red Carpet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/straight-to-the-red-carpet)*.

> The first time Vedis transmigrated into the novel “Princess of Eventide,” she followed the original plot exactly for seven straight years—and lost almost everyone she loved along the way. Lucky for her, **she’s been sent back to the start again along with her close friend Rosanne, the princess of Moselberg**. Together, they will do everything in their power to **prevent the violent rebellion** and save the people they love. But when they start making different choices, what else will change? And will they discover the traitors in time?

The synopsis is a solid match for the question. The main character possessed the character of a novel and followed the events of the book, including a rebellion against the country that resulted in her family (and many others) dying. The book ends with the princess's marriage, but after that Vedis wakes up 7 years in the past again. She is unexpectedly summoned by the princess, who promptly reveals that she also went back in time, and wants to prevent the rebellion.

[image: Both characters went back in time]

I can't confirm the part about forming a team of skilled female knights, but it seems plausible.